# Azure Data Factory compare and copy missing rows

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I've got 2 tables, and I want to copy only the new rows from table A to table B.

So far I've declared two sources:

- Table A on sqlserver1
- Table B on sqlserver2

Now I'm at a loss about how to say only take those rows that are missing in tableB. I've got a compound key. In T-SQL, I'd just use a left join with multiple on statements.

Comment: table a and table b have id unique right? .. if yes you can using in data flow

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want copy data from table a to table with only new rows from table a. you must create data flow like this. I assume that table a is table source and table b is sink (table destination)

[image: data flow copy from table a to table b]

2. you can add lookup activity as below:
   for example "PLANT" is unique value from table A or Id_column
   [image]
3. you can add lookup activity like this: add column "flag" is using to flag from that Id do you have

[image]

4. the last is using conditional split like this:
   [image]
5. the last, is you can using sink to Table B ...

I hope my explain can help your problem. I'm sory if my english is bad ...

Comment: Ahhh - I was trying to use pipelines. Wrong tool for the job eh?

Comment: Yes its pipeline, you can drag data flow activity on your pipeline. Before that you create some data flow first ..

Comment: it seems that I can just do an ‘not exist’ although the debugger seems to come up with an inductee information message about too small sample size or null datasets. Makes sense since both input sources actually matched in terms of data. 

I wonder what happens if you filter out to the point where no data is available to the sink. Does it error?